# How to apply Google recaptcha with android & firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, gradle

I need to get Recaptcha and sent it to the server. I connect firebase to my android project, I read the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/safetynet-provider?hl=nb). I do steps from 1 to 3, but when I read the next steps, I don't find where I can get a captcha. I think at web-client it looks like a standard Recaptcha button, but I never see equal things on android. How can I get the Recaptcha code?